# How to successfully install Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 in a container?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install VS 2019 Build Tools in a container, using a modified version of the instructions provided by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019

The differences between that example and what I am trying to do is the component being installed -- they use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools` while I am trying to use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools` (I am not interested in Azure, this is purely for CI builds of C++ applications).

Additionally, while I am installing from a layout (offline installer) that I created from the online installer yesterday, this same error happens if I use `vs_buildtools.exe` directly in the Dockerfile.

I see this error in the log files:

```
2020-06-23T14:10:12 : Verbose : Visual Studio Installer (2.6.2035.522 : release) ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vs_installershell.exe","--","/finalizeInstall","install","--layoutPath","C:\\unpacked\\vs_bootstrap\\VS2019_Build_Tools","--in","C:\\unpacked\\vs_bootstrap\\VS2019_Build_Tools\\Response.json","--installPath","C:\\TEMP\\BuildTools","--quiet","--norestart","--nocache","--noWeb","-–add","Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools","--locale","en-US","--activityId","410d2d14-aac9-4e90-90b0-c257df2fe29b"]
2020-06-23T14:10:12 : Error : Error: Unsupported option: –
    at CommandLineErrorHandler.emit (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:392962)
    at CommandLineErrorHandler.emitError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:392528)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:230340
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CommandLineParser.normalizeAndValidateOptionNames (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:229836)
    at CommandLineParser.parse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:226636)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:353835)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:128)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:223183)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\StubMain.js:4:128)
```

I have also posted this in the Visual Studio "Community" forums, but there is no telling if anything will come of that, so I am asking here as well.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue